# Does anyone know how to create a zipper?

Tags: modeling

I'm looking for a tutorial on how to create a zipper in blender.  For some reason I had it in my head that there was an add-on that did it, but looks like there isn't unless i missed one.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial on how to add zipper teeth to an already existing mesh (it doesn't have to work as the jacket will be open, i just want the effect.)

Either that or give me an idiots guide to zipper creation.  I would have thought that with the amount of clothing being made for characters a tutorial would be a lot easier to find.

Comment: A quick google search gives [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waCN_4q7ens) as the first result ;)

Comment: A quick search using my favorite search engine reveals a zipper tutorial, by Ray Mairlot at [Youtube](http://youtu.be/waCN_4q7ens), also linked to from BlenderNation